# Write a program to round a number to the next multiple of 10 given the following conditions?

Tags: java, if-statement

> Write a program to Round a number to the next multiple of 10 if its ones digit is 5 or more, otherwise round it the previous multiple of 10.So, 25 and 26 round to 30 where as 23 and 24 round to 20. 20 also rounds to 20. You have been given 4 ints as input. Round each of the input values and return their sum.

**MyApproach**

I created 2 functions in the first function I counted the sum of all 4 numbers.

In the second function I checked the UnitDigtit if>=5 &&<=9 Then proceed with set of statements given in the question.

else

I checked if Its a one digit or two or any digit number.If One digit I returned num=0 else I proceded with the sets of statements.

## Sample Input #1

sumRounded(11,15,23,30)

## Sample Output #1

80 (11 rounds to 10, 15 to 20, 23 to 20 and 30 to 30)

## Sample Input #2

sumRounded(1,3,7,9)

## Sample Output #2

20

```
public int sumRounded(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4)
{
    
    int a=checkRound(num1);
    int b=checkRound(num2);
    int c=checkRound(num3);
    int d=checkRound(num4);
    return a+b+c+d;
}   
   
public int checkRound(int num)
 {
      int a=num%10;
      if((a>=5) &&(a<=9))
      {
         if(a==5)
          {
              num=num+5;
          }
         else if(a==6)
          {
               num=num+6;
          }
          else if(a==7)
          {
                num=num+7;
          }
          else if(a==8)
          {
                num=num+8;
          }
          else if(a==9)
          {
               num=num+9;
          }
          return num;
       }
         else
         {
             if((num/10)!=0)
             {
                 if(a==1)
                    {
                        num=num-1;
                    }
                 else if(a==2)
                    {
                        num=num-2;
                    }
                 else if(a==3)
                    {
                        num=num-3;
                    }
                 else if(a==4)
                    {
                        num=num-4;
                    }
                 return num;
             }
             else
             {
                 
              return num=0;
             }
          }
         
        

     }
```

Results:

```
  Parameters           Actual Output    Expected Output 

'289' '3' '25' '308'   644              630
```

Comment: you all have put your code.All are right can you tell Why I am wrong.I have dry run the code.

Comment: For Example 289,3,25,308=290+0+30+310=640?And I am getting 644 Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Rounding

If the remainder is less than 5, subtract it from `num`. Otherwise, add ten minus the remainder to the `num`. Something like,

```
static int checkRound(int num) {
    int rem = num % 10;
    return rem < 5 ? num - rem : num + (10 - rem);
}
```

**or** use [`Math.round(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-) like

```
static int checkRound(int num) {
    return Math.round((float) num / 10) * 10;
}
```

### [Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

You could also implement `sumRounded` as a varargs method with a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

```
static int sumRounded(int... nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int num : nums) {
        sum += checkRound(num);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

### Testing

Then you could test it like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sumRounded(11, 15, 23, 30)); // == 80
    System.out.println(sumRounded(1, 3, 7, 9)); // == 20
}
```

Comment: @Jasonarora Literally, because math. One example, `if(a==6) { num=num+6;}` means the remainder is `6` and you add `6` - `6+6` is `12`. Not a multiple of a ten. You do the same with `7`, `8` and `9`. Your `else` block is `num - a` (in my example `a` is `rem`).

Comment: @Jasonarora in addition your else block is quite confusing, there is no need to check if `num/10 != 0`. Just delete this condition and the else part of this condition and your program, despite beeing overly complicated, would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix you way do the following but Exbury's answer is a shorter way of doing it.

1. If you are rounding up you should add the 10 minus the number, not the number itself. So for example, 26 rounded up should be 26+(10-6) = 26+(4) = 30

Comment: This also results in same value 26+(4) = 30?

Comment: No, your code currently does 26+(6)=32 because you get 26%10 which is 6 and then you add 6 to 26 which is 32 not 30

Comment: `num/10 will always equal 0`, if i divide `11` by `10` the result be `1`. Or am i missunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the reminder check inside checkRounded method

```
int number = 23;
int output=0;
if(number%10<5){
    output=(number/10)*10;
}
else{
    output=((number/10)+1)*10;
}

System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply put following code in you chexkRound method

```
 int a = num % 10;
 if ((a >= 5) && (a <= 9)) {
     num = 10 * (num / 10 + 1);
 } else {
     num = 10 * (num / 10);
 }
 return num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the following code perfectly suits your need

//code starts

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The answer is: " + getSum(2,5,19));
}

public static int getSum(int... nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int n : nums) {
        int lastDigit = n % 10;
        if (lastDigit >= 5) {
            sum = sum + n + (10 - (lastDigit));
        } else {
            sum = sum + 10 * (n / 10);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

//code ends